# How to call parent method Angular 2 with returning value?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have two methods in parent component:

```
public isOpen(index: number): boolean {
    const block = this.dropDownBlocks.find(b => b.index === index);
    return block.open;
  }

  public openDropDown(index: number) {
    const block = this.dropDownBlocks.find(b => b.index === index);
    const i = this.dropDownBlocks.indexOf(block);
    this.dropDownBlocks[i].open = !block.open;
  }
```

No matter what the do.

In child component I determined:

```
@Output() openTab = new EventEmitter<number>();
@Output() opened = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

And below in child component I have written:

```
public openDropDown(index: number) {
   this.openTab.emit(index);
}

public isOpen(index: number) {
   return this.opened.emit(index);
}
```

Template child is:

```
<div class="header" (click)="openDropDown(2)"></div>
<div class="body" [hidden]="!isOpen(2)">
```

It means I invoke child method and transfer the initiative to parent method with the same name:

```
public openDropDown(index: number) {
       this.openTab.emit(index);
    }
```

So, child component is included in parent like this:

```
<app-missed-plan (openTab)="openDropDown($event)" (opened)="isOpen($event)"></app-missed-plan>
```

Problem is `isOpen()` does not work and does not return value

Comment: That is because nothing triggers the `isOpen()` method in the child component. This means that the `opened` EventEmitter never emits and the parent component never gets invoked.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write one line of code. `isOpen()` is called from template, updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not return here. Just emit the value from child component. That should call the parent `isOpen($event)`

```
public isOpen(index: number) {
   this.opened.emit(index);
}
```

EDIT : from the comments below, it is clear that you are trying to return data from parent to child. It is best to use `@Input()` instead of returning data from parent component method.

And also you do not need two emitters in your case. One `Output` and one `Input` variables are enough

Comment: Is it in child component?

Comment: I tried: `public isOpen(index: number) {
    return this.opened.emit(index);
  }`

Comment: I have return, anyway child `isOpen()` works, but I can not get changed value from parent

Comment: How are you calling child method `isOpen()` ? Thorugh this line `<div class="body" [hidden]="!isOpen(2)">` ?

Comment: I call it from child template like: `<div class="body" [hidden]="!isOpen(1)">`

Comment: See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4ylyy It does call parent component method on emit.

Comment: Yes, I have the same code, but I assume that function does not return value to template here from parent: `[hidden]="!isOpen(1)"`

Comment: `emit()` returns void

Comment: May be to do like this: `(opened)="return isOpen($event)"`?

Comment: Problem is that parent function returns value that I need to get in child component

Comment: You can use `@Input()` variable for that to pass data from parent to child.

Comment: In this case I do duplicates of methods in child component

Comment: Why it is not possible to emit event and get result from parent

Comment: Event emitting is always from `child->parent`.  To pass data from `parent-> child`, you should always use `@Input()`

Comment: Okay use it like this: `[dropDownBlocks]="dropDownBlocks" `  `@Input() dropDownBlocks: any;`?

Comment: Yes perfect. `@Input()` goes in child component.

Comment: Check updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4ylyy . I also updated my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I used a callback function in my implementation. The child component passes a value and callback to the parent, the parent does work with the value and returns the result of that work to the child component using the callback.

Child component:

```
@Output() opened = new EventEmitter<{ value: number, onResult: Function }>()

public isOpen(index) {
    this.opened.emit({
        value: index,
        onResult: (result) => doSomethingWithResult
    })
}
```

Parent template:

```
<app-parent 
     (opened)="doSomething($event.value, $event.onResult)">
</app-parent>
```

Parent component:

```
public doSomething(index, onResult) {
    returnValue = doStuffWithIndex
    onResult(returnValue)
}
```